# Can I display an Object's type by default in the Firefox Developer console?

Tags: javascript, firefox

In Firefox Developer Edition (44.0a2 (2015-11-14) on OSX), if I `console.log` an object in the console, it appears like this:

```
Object { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", language: "en" }
```

Is there a way to have the Firefox javascript console display the Object's type instead of just 'Object'? The Chrome developer tools have this feature and display:

```
G…r.init {firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", language: "en"}
```

Code:

```
(function(global, $) {

    var Greetr = function(firstName, lastName, language) {
        return new Greetr.init(firstName, lastName, language);   
    }

    Greetr.prototype = {};

    Greetr.init = function(firstName, lastName, language) {

        var self = this;
        self.firstName = firstName || '';
        self.lastName = lastName || '';
        self.language = language || 'en';

    }

    Greetr.init.prototype = Greetr.prototype;

    global.Greetr = global.G$ = Greetr;

}(window, jQuery));


var g = G$('John', 'Doe');
console.log(g);
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "type"? `Object` is definitely the correct data type.

Comment: `Greetr.prototype.type = function(args) {
      return $.type(args || this)
    }; var g = G$('John', 'Doe');
console.log(g, g.type());` ?

Comment: Thanks. Almost everything is an object in JS so I would like a hint as to whether it is a function object, for example. I updated the question.

Comment: Well, `g` is not a function object. I don't have the developer edition, but when I log a function, I see `function foo()` in the console...

Comment: @codecowboy Tried `console.log($.type(g))` ?

Comment: @guest271314 if you mean ```typeof``` that returns 'object' as does ```$.type(g)```

Comment: @codecowboy _"if you mean `typeof` that returns 'object' as does `$.type(g)`"_ Is this expected result ? , resolve Question ? Not certain what requirement is ?